# Identifier Expected Error in Pizza Class Problem

Tags: java, compiler-errors, identifier

I keep getting an identifier expected error where it says "public double calcTotal(calcCost){" towards the end of my code. Note that I'm calling a method from a different class. What is the problem there? Also, please feel free to point out any other errors you see in my code. I'm scared that once I fix this one error, 10 more will pop up when I try to compile again. Thank you!

```
public class PizzaOrder {
  private String [] m_Pizza; //array for base type Pizza
  private int m_numPizzas;

  //default constructor
  public PizzaOrder() {
    m_Pizza = null;//new String[0]
    m_numPizzas = 0;
  }

  //overloaded Pizza
  public PizzaOrder(String [] Pizza, int numPizzas) {
    m_Pizza = Pizza;
    m_numPizzas = numPizzas;
  }

  //public methods
  public void setPizza (String [] Pizza){
    m_Pizza = Pizza;
  }
  public String getPizza () {
    return m_Pizza;
  }
  public void setNumPizzas (int numPizzas) {
    m_numPizzas = numPizzas;
  }
  public int getNumPizzas () {
    return numPizzas;
  }

  public void addPizza(Pizza pizza) {
    if (m_Pizza.length() <= m_numPizzas) {
      m_Pizza.length() = m_numPizzas;
      //m_Pizza[m_numPizzas] = Pizza; //pizza array has same amount of items as numPizzas
      m_numPizzas++;
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("Adding an additional pizza was unuccessful.");
    }
  }

public double calcTotal(calcCost){
    double totalCost = 0;
    double Cost = calcCost(); //calling calcCost function
    for (int i = 0; i < m_Pizza.length(); i++) { //goes through array
      calcCost(m_Pizza[i]); //calculates cost for each pizza in array
      Cost += totalCost; //adds each cost to total
    return totalCost;
    }
  }

  public String toString() {
    double total = calcTotal(calcCost); //stores calcTotal function in total variable
    System.out.println("You ordered a " + m_Pizza + ". Your total cost is: " + total);
  }

}
```

Comment: Identify 'calcCost' in the method signature 'calcTotal' like int or double. Also it is okay to get exceptions but you need to understand them and fix.

Comment: `public double calcTotal(calcCost)` -> `public double calcTotal(double calcCost)`

Comment: first of all correct the indentation of your code - hard to read, error-prone, ... `(calcCost)` is valid in calling a method but for declaring one you need to declare the parameter (missing its type)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there seems to be many problems with this method, 
I have added comments in line

```
public double calcTotal(calcCost){
  double totalCost = 0;
  double Cost = calcCost(); // is there really a zero parameter method ?
  for (int i = 0; i < m_Pizza.length(); i++) { 
    calcCost(m_Pizza[i]); // this takes a parameter but does not use the return value
    Cost += totalCost; // totalCost is always zero, do you mean totalCost += Cost; ?
    return totalCost;  // you are returning this value with in the for loop
  }

  // compile error here as it is expecting some value to be returned
```

}

Hints: move the return value outside of your loop

Save value of calCost to Cost

Add value of Cost to totalCost

Also as @markspace mentions there is something wrong with the parameter to this method, actually is any needed?

Comment: I fixed the return value, but I'm still getting that same error. Also would it make sense to change calcCost(m_Pizza[i]); to m_Pizza[i].calcCost();

Comment: I have mentioned 5 different problems - fix them all

Answer (score 0):

You should add "return" statement at the end of method after for loop finishes.

```
 public double calcTotal(calcCost){
    double totalCost = 0;
    double Cost = calcCost(); //calling calcCost function
    for (int i = 0; i < m_Pizza.length(); i++) { //goes through array
      calcCost(m_Pizza[i]); //calculates cost for each pizza in array
      Cost += totalCost; //adds each cost to total

    }
    return totalCost;
  }
```

Think of when m_Pizza variable is empty, control will not go into for loop then what will method return?, so above is the fix.

Comment: plenty of other problems too

Comment: what is the type of argument `calcCost`? reason of error being asked about

Comment: @Carlos it's a double. I had double there before, but there were errors. When I removed it the errors were gone.

Comment: @jamie well, my comment was directed to Rahul, the author of **this** *answer*. But its the same error `public double calcTotal(calcCost)` is not valid, there must be a type for the argument, e.g. `public double calcTotal(doubel calcCost)`. Just because you get a different error does not mean it is correct - you asked what is the error there, it is just repeated in this *answer*